# How to evenly distribute data to multiple GPUs using Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, gpu

I am using Keras=2.3.1 with Tensorflow-gpu=2.0.0 backend. While I trained model on two RTX 2080 ti 11G GPUs, it allocates all data to '/gpu:0',and nothing changed with '/gpu:1'. Surely, the second GPU not used at all.

However, every GPU could work if I selected only one GPU.

Moreover, the two gpus can be run parallelly in Pytorch.

Follow some instances, I try to run multi-gpus with these codes:

[image]

[image]

Below is NVIDIA-SMI output when I run a multi-gpus model.

[image]

and cuda = 10.1, cudnn = 7.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the docs on TensorFlow GPU usage](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu)

If you wanted data parallelism where you run a copy of your model on multiple GPUs and split the data between them, you could use the `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy`.

The `tf.distribute.Strategy` docs are also [a good source to read](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/Strategy).

**Also**, you should also profile your application; adding a second GPU has the potential to reduce performance depending on what your bottlenecks are.